# Django custom image field that can have crop information

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to find a way to create a custom image field that can take extra crop information.

A custom image field that creates two db columns one for image path the other is for image's crop information (it will be dynamic top, left, width, height informations that user can set via a js component ).

Can a model field be customized to create and validate two db columns? Or is this a wrong way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Django model fields can only map to one database column, so until they provide an easy solution it's not possible.

You can take a look at this [workaround](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2008/01/08/fuzzydates-or-one-django-model-field-multiple-database-columns/).

Anyway what you can do is override the model `save` method and use `PIL` for example to crop the image and set it equal to the cropped image field.

To override an model field, it's pretty simple and easy and you can pass extra parameter. Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) everything is well explained.